# How move an iAd to top of screen in an iOS7 app that uses canDisplayBannerAds?

Tags: ios, ios7, banner-ads, iad

It seems that adding an iAd to an iOS7 app is straightforward by using `canDisplayBannerAds`. Basically I add the iAd framework, import the header and then in the view controller do this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
    [super awakeFromNib];
}
```

This seems to work fine in the simulator (though ads frequently don't seem to show up). When an iAd does show up it is correctly at the bottom of the screen.

However how do I move the iAd to the top of the screen instead?

My game app has a few buttons at the bottom of the screen and the guidelines Apple suggests are to avoid accidental clicking of the iAd by moving the iAd to another area of the screen. But then I can't find any info on how to move this iAd.

(I'm totally new to iAds and was hoping for minimal code changes by using `canDisplayBannerAds` so any suggestions greatly appreciated).

Comment: did you find any solution for the problem. I am too looking for solution. If yes then please share your answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for. I think I read the question correct. I am just setting my `iAd` up now, and I also needed to move the `ADBannerView` on the screen.

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{    

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];    
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];    
    [banner setAlpha:1];    
    [UIView commitAnimations];    

    banner.frame = CGRectMake(0,518,320,50);    
}
```

Again, this is just what I did and it works for me.